# Unable to resolve some libraries after moving from android studio Eel up to android studio flamingo and upgrading gradle to 8

Tags: java, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

i was implementing an **android** app in **java** and everything was running correctly until i upgrade my **android studio Eel version** to  **android studio Flamingo version** and move up my **gradle** **version** from **7.3.1** to **8.0.0** .Since then , my project can't compile anymore and i got the following error message :

```
Configuration cache state could not be cached: field `compileTimeDependencies` of task `:app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug` of type `com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsTask`: error writing value of type 'org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection'
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.whiteelephant:monthandyearpicker:1.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

How could i figure it out ?

Comment: As a first step, try the "Invalidate Caches" menu on the File menu. Sometimes helps where caching is mentioned